# How can I decode a .txt file into a image format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a .txt file that has pixel coordinates and pixel values. I tried to visualize it in png and jpeg formats which are compressed 8-bit, but I wanted it to be in 16-bit image format like a tiff. I have tried saving my image in tiff format but it is not the image I expected it has a lot of noise and I cannot even see the image when I open the file when compared to png or jpeg.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 



file = open('filename')
data = pd.read_table(file, header=None, skiprows=8, decimal=",")
data = data.iloc[:, :]
rows, cols = data.shape

na = np.array(data)
plt.imshow(na)

plt.imsave('mes.png',an)
na.save('myimg.tif')
```

What am I doing wrong while implementing this, Any suggestions or changes?
Any help is appreciated, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a general guideline, try to avoid pasting links to GDrive because those links can break at times. I'd suggest using SO's builtin image uploader for pictures. For the text, you should try pasting it in with the proper formatting for code or use pastebin

Comment: I have tried to upload them using the built-in image uploader but my images and data are too big to upload natively. That is the reason I have uploaded using Gdrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not normalised your data to the correct range of 0..65535 for an unsigned 16-bit TIFF or PNG file.

I am using the OpenCV function here, but you can use Numpy or straight Python to get the same result. So, after converting to a Numpy array

```
... your code ...
na = np.array(data)

import cv2
# Normalise (scale) to range 0..65535
sc = cv2.normalize(na, None, alpha=0, beta=65535, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype = cv2.CV_16U)

# Save, using any ONE of the following methods
Image.fromarray(sc).save('result.tif')
Image.fromarray(sc).save('result.png')
cv2.imwrite('result.tif', sc)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', sc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was not thinking about normalization.

Comment: Cool - glad it's working now. Remember, questions (and answers) are free, so if you get stuck again, come back and ask another. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi I have a small question does normalization retain the same pixel values as the input file or will it change accordingly to the min and max.

Comment: It will make the brightest pixel in your image 65535 and the darkest pixel will be 0. There are other ways of normalising though depending on your needs.